# Create document library structure in a Vs2012 project

Tags: document-library, 2013, visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to create a Visual Studio 2012 project containing multiple document libraries with folders and subfolders that can be builded/deployed to a sharepoint site?

My need is to deploy the classification plan to multiple sharepoint sites. I need to be able to compare my project to what's actually deployed to that site, and create the missing parts / update the existing ones. I need to leave untouched what's in the site but not in the project.

There might be other ways to achieve what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion would be a feature event receiver. In the feature *activating* perform your checks to see if the doc libraries exist and if the folders exist and if not create them.

Here are two articles from MSDN to get you started. The same process for 2010 will apply to SharePoint 2013 in this instance.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231604.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee231604(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks. So whenever the feature gets activated for a site, we create the whole hierarchy from a config file. We would have to manage ourselves the creation and updating of the structure.

Comment: Yes and no. Where the configuration is stored and managed is up to you. You could do this in a resource file, a static class, or even a database for internal, on-premises deployments (I've never heard of using a database for this but it could be done). For on-premises deployments the sky is really the limit. There is also a feature upgrading event that you should research as well. This can be very useful in adding components (workflows, list/library event receivers) to lists/libraries that already exist.

Comment: Thanks again. I went down the feature road with a xml config file for my list of document library to create. Upon activating the feature, it creates the whole hierarchy. I tried adding the lists directly into the project, but whenever you want to deploy changes, it deletes the current library and re-creates it.